# Restricted Sum Simplification

Tags: combinatorics, summation

I am trying to find the coefficients $b_i$ for a restrictive sum that I am trying to simplify:
$$\sum_{\sum_{k=1}^K x_k=X} e^{\alpha \sum_{k=1}^K kx_k}=\sum_{i=X}^{XK}b_ie^{\alpha i}$$
(where $x_k$ are positive integers) and scoured a bit trying to find some identities, but the closest I found was the multinomial theorem.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem

Was wondering if anyone knew of any references/resources that deal with restrictive sums.

UPDATE:
I recently found that a way to generate this polynomial is via q-Binomials (also known as Gaussian binomials https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_binomial_coefficient) via:
$$ \binom{X+K-1}{X}_q q^X=\sum_{i=X}^{XK}b_ie^{\alpha i}$$
where $q=e^\alpha$.  However there still does not seem to be a closed form for $b_i$.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a calculation of the generating function. If you call your sum $a_X$, you seem to be asking for $f(z)=\sum_X\, a_X\,z^X$. This function is the product of $K$ generating functions $f_k(z)$ for $k=1..K$, where each
$$f_k(z)=\sum_{\ell\ge1}e^{\alpha k \ell}z^\ell=\frac{e^{\alpha k}z}{1-e^{\alpha k }z}.$$ Multiplying these, we get
$$f(z)=\prod_{k=1}^K \frac{e^{\alpha k}z}{1-e^{\alpha k }z}=\frac{z^Ke^{\alpha K(K+1)/2}}{\prod_{k=1}^K (1-e^{\alpha k }z)}.$$
In just about any application, you'll have to deal with the singularities at $z=e^{-\alpha k}$, but that seems to be a different question.

Comment: Thanks!  I did not state my question as clearly because I actually wanted a generating function for the coefficients $b_i$ for $\sum_{i=K}^{XK}b_i e^{\alpha i}$.  However your answer probably relates to q-Binomials which I will update the question with.